# Adding value to int array

Tags: postgresql, array, postgresql-extensions

I looked at the postgres website and to add a integer to a intarray it says int[] + int.  I have a int array in a table and I eventually want to insert the array with another value added to it into another table.  So testing with a select statement I am not sure where I am messing up.

So a am doing:

```
SELECT myarray + 9::integer from foo
ERROR: operator does not exist: smallint[] + integer
```

What am I missing.  It looks just like the postgres website on intarrays from 9.1 postgres.

Comment: Note that 9.1 is unsupported and no longer maintained. You should upgrade as soon as possible. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator

```
myarray || 9
```

Details in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/9.1/functions-array.html

Answer (score 2):

[`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) is an extension, you need to add it first to use its *push element onto array (add it to end of array)* opperator.. Before you add the extension, you get this.

```
SELECT ARRAY[1]::smallint[] + 1;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: smallint[] + integer
LINE 1: SELECT ARRAY[1]::smallint[] + 1;
                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Then we add the extension and retry,

```
test=# CREATE EXTENSION intarray ;
CREATE EXTENSION

test=# SELECT ARRAY[1]::smallint[] + 1;
 ?column? 
----------
 {1,1}
(1 row)
```

Or you can use the regular [array-to-element concatenation `||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
SELECT ARRAY[1] || 1;
 ?column? 
----------
 {1,1}
(1 row)
```

But be careful, [it seems to be substantially slower](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/173625/2639). Also, in your example you're using smallint, you may have to explicitly cast the rhs to smallint.

```
SELECT ARRAY[1::smallint] || 5::smallint;
```

-vs-

```
SELECT ARRAY[1::smallint] || 5;
```

Comment: No need for an extension. The built-in `||` operator will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ya I actually just figured it out.  I need to use something like this

```
select array_append(myarray,1::smallint) from foo
```

I was using wrong command.

Comment: array_append is just the functional backend of `||`. For clarity, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to use it?

Comment: It's less clear, `||` is known as concatenation and it's used everywhere with all different types. Type `\doS+ ||` in psql. All opperators in PostgreSQL have functional backends, we usually treat them as implementation details though and don't use them.