# Why is intarray's push `+` so much faster than array-to-element concatenation `||`?

Tags: postgresql, performance, array, database-internals, postgresql-extensions, postgresql-performance

When it comes to using arrays of ints, I always default to using `intarray`. But, now I'm wondering why is the default concatenation so much slower.

This answer probably requires some understanding of internals. Internally, `intarray`'s calls [`intarray_push_elem`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/3a0d473192b2045cbaf997df8437e7762d34f3ba/contrib/intarray/_int_op.c#L328), and `||` calls [`array_append`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/23c6eb03360d270051bf7dcb289ecb0cd114d29f/src/backend/utils/adt/array_userfuncs.c#L100)

## Sample Data

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
CREATE TABLE foo AS
  SELECT ARRAY[x::int] AS bar
  FROM generate_series(1,1e7)
    AS gs(x);
```

## Same result

```
SELECT ARRAY[1] + 42 = ARRAY[1] || 42;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

## With `||`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT bar || 42 FROM foo;

                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..198528.55 rows=9999884 width=25) (actual time=0.029..5193.752 rows=10000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.051 ms
 Execution time: 5679.489 ms
(3 rows)
```

## With `+` from `intarray` extension

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT bar + 42 FROM foo;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..198528.55 rows=9999884 width=25) (actual time=0.026..2066.786 rows=10000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.052 ms
 Execution time: 2388.462 ms
(3 rows)
```

Routinely `intarray`'s `+` is faster than `||`. Why is `||` so slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if `||` is doing a lot more for multidimensional arrays.

For instance with `||` catching [the following case](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/23c6eb03360d270051bf7dcb289ecb0cd114d29f/src/backend/utils/adt/array_userfuncs.c#L139)

```
SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1]] || 5;
ERROR:  argument must be empty or one-dimensional array
```

Whereas, with `+` the array is flattened..

```
SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1]] + 5;
 ?column? 
----------
 {1,5}
(1 row)
```

In addition it seems intarray [does not handle nulls](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/55c3391d1e6a201b5b891781d21fe682a8c64fe6/contrib/intarray/_int.h#L18).

```
SELECT ARRAY[null]::int[] + 5;
ERROR:  array must not contain nulls
```

It also seems `||` uses `PG_RETURN_DATUM` instead of passing by reference which seems to be what `+` uses with `PG_RETURN_POINTER`.